# Stop loop if sip register has response

Tags: perl, sip

**Stop loop if  sip register  has response**

can i stop this loop

if i get and response 404 403 or any .

How can I extract the server response to my registration attempt

```
$response = $ua->register(expires => 40000 , cb_final => sub {
    my ($what,%args)  = @_;
});
$ua->loop(5);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable by checking the code and using a stopvar, i.e. something like this:

```
my $stopvar;
$response = $ua->register(expires => 40000 , cb_final => sub {
    my ($what,%args)  = @_;
    # maybe check $args{code} in case of $what eq 'FAIL'
    $stopvar = 1;
});
$ua->loop(5, \$stopvar);
```

Comment: thank u sir . how i can set time out to sockt conenction

Comment: the defualt time out is 10 sec

Comment: @somavasamco: the timeout is the first  argument in loop. See also the documentation of loop in Net::SIP::Simple

Comment: like if ther port is close . the socket have time out to try connection . how i can control socket timeout

Comment: @somavasamco: connections are done non-blocking in Net::SIP. There should be no need to have a specific socket timeout since it is already covered by the timeout given in `loop`. Net::SIP does not provide more granular control than this.